# visual studio qt5 plugins not working on release

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins, release, qt5

I'm got this project where i'm showing images with a qt5 interface, i'm simply setting the Pixmap of a label with the qimage pixmap

The thing is, it's working on a debug build, but not on a release build and i dont understand why.

I already got a folder in my .Exe folder named "plugins" and a subfolder in it named "imageformats", and in this folder the file named "qjpeg.dll"

So i coming here to see if someone has an idea on why it doesn't work ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I would first check the C run time dependencies (debug / release & static / dynamic) on the various exe and dll involved in your project, with tool like `Walker Dependency`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you developed your app in Qt Creator, and that you're not using a .qrc file.

This is the folder structure that Qt expects (left side if you launch your app from Qt Creator, right side if you launch your app by double-clicking its icon):

```
[Dev]\pic.jpg                        =>  [App]\pic.jpg
[Dev]\release\app.exe                =>  [App]\app.exe
[Qt]\bin\*.dll                       =>  [App]\*.dll
[Qt]\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll  =>  [App]\platforms\qwindows.dll
[Qt]\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg.dll  =>  [App]\imageformats\qjpeg.dll
---------------------------------------------------------------------
    [Qt]  = Folder where you installed Qt
    [Dev] = Folder where you built your app
    [App] = Folder where you want to deploy your app
```

Two common mistakes:

- If you launch from Qt Creator, make sure your picture file is in [Dev] (different folders are used for Debug and Release mode)
- If you launch by double-clicking, get rid of the "plugins" folder

Comment: thanks, i'm lauching from visual studio...but i saw on internet that i needed the "plugins" folder, but removing this folder worked :)

Comment: Strangely, I have a similar problem and this solution didn't work. When deploying to a non-dev machine, my program runs but is unable to load jpg images. `QImageReader::supportedImageFormats();` doesn't list jpg. Even if I copy the full `imageformats` folder (with qjpeg in it) into my application path just as you described, it doesn't work. I've found a hint about adding `QTPLUGIN += qjpeg` to my project file, but it doesn't make any difference. I'm using Qt 5.5 with Qt Creator.

Comment: Using `windeployqt.exe` solved my problem, by copying a few other DLLs into my app directory, so it seems that `imageformats` alone is not enough.

Comment: @vsz: Out of curiosity, what other DLLs did you need? Also, this article might be of interest to you: http://wiki.qt.io/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows

Comment: I'm also using `windeployqt`, and it creates folders and import dlls according to the details given in this answer. Still, I have the same issue as others here: it seems like the dlls 
In `imageformats` aren't being used. Or perhaps they couldn't be loaded, due to other missing dlls. I can reproduce the issue on my own machine: jpeg loads if I launch from QtCreator, not if I launch the program myself.